# Unity 2D, Shooting with bow Instantiate problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi everyone I have a little problem with my bow shooting script. I mean i want to shoot an arrow when play the one of last frames from my animation. I try to do it by setting an firePoint GameObject, put it by recording in my Animation Tab in desired frame. It's of course disabled but its enabled when animation plays and then its again disabled. So the problem is: 
- When i hit button which match my Shooting input, the animation plays,
- My Instantiate appears and it produces multiple arrows,
- When its disabled it stops to produce arrows.

I want to produce only one arrow. Could anyone help?

---

**CombatScript.cs:**

```
/*    private bool shootBow;
 *    public bool needReload = false;
 *    public float reloadTime = 1.5f;
 *    public float realoadCD;
 */
public void RangeAttack()
{
    if (needReload == false && gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControls>().grounded == true && Input.GetButtonDown("Ranged"))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("shootBow");

        attack1 = false; // Melle attacks sets to false in case of lag or smth.
        attack2 = false;
        attack3 = false;



        needReload = true;

        if (needReload == true)
        {
            reloadCD = reloadTime;
        }
    }

    if (reloadCD > 0 && needReload == true)
    {
        reloadCD -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (reloadCD <= 0)
    {
        reloadCD = 0;
        needReload = false;
    }
    if (firePoint.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
    {
        Instantiate(Missile, new Vector3(firePoint.position.x + 1, firePoint.position.y), firePoint.rotation);
        Debug.Log("It's a bird, a plane, no.. it's arrow.");
    }
}
```

**Arrow Controller.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrowController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }

        Debug.Log("Arrow Broke");
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
        //Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

    }
}
```

**Example of my situation:**

[image: Example of my situation]

**Example of true/false needReload statement:**

[image: Example of true/false needReload statement]

in right Inspector you have my Player informations, in left (or bottom) Inspector you have Missile (Arrow) inspector

Comment: Where do you call RangeAttack() ?

Comment: yeah if its a mouse event or input, you need to change it to `OnMouseButtonDown` or `OnKeyDown' if you have it in `OnMouseButton` or `OnKeyPress` it will call it repeatedly, but using the down or up event will call it only once per click

Comment: @Z3RP - I call it in FixedUpdate()

Comment: So your question is you want to shoot ONE arrow at your last frame of the Animation right ?

Comment: Yes i wanted to make it work exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html) and for example a boolean that is your firerate.

And you Code can look something like this:

```
float LastShoot;
        float FireRate = 10;
        public void OnShoot()
        {
            if (LastShoot <= 0)
            {
                //Shoot your arrow
                LastShoot = FireRate;
            }
        }
        void Update()
        {
            LastShoot -= 0.5f;
        }
```

But i don't know if this is the best solution to calculate a firerate. If someone knows a better one feel free and edit my awnser :)

Answer (score 0):

Okey... couple of hours later (which I wasted...). The answer was ridiculously easy. For future "problems" like that... the thing was to create in my script function called "ProduceArrow()"and (additionaly to what i did) something like Animation Event it's in Animation Tab, when you create your animation timeline you just need to call it clicking right mouse button and then choose it and pick proper function.

[Some feedback - gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djo1k.gif)

Answer (score -1):

The way your code works right now, Instatiate will be called every frame. So one button click, which is probably longer than one frame, will trigger multiple arrows, so you need to set a condition for when you want Instantiate to be called. You already calculate a reload time, which is exactly what you need. You just need to include it in your if-statement like follows:

```
if (firePoint.gameObject.activeSelf == true && !needReload)
{
    Instantiate(Missile, new Vector3(firePoint.position.x + 1, firePoint.position.y), firePoint.rotation);
    Debug.Log("It's a bird, a plane, no.. it's arrow.");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetly, when i hit shoot button my player only did its animation. But even Debug.Log didnt't worked. My RangeAttack() function is in FixedUpdate() should i move it to Update() ?

Comment: No it should stay in FixedUpdated(). Can you check if the needReload boolean is correctly set to false when Instantiate should be called?

Comment: It looks well, I mean it is working as its coded and how i whished to make it work. When i click V (which is my shooting button) - its set to True and my counter is going to 0 when it hits 0 value its again false. I posted a gif in my orginal message to show You how it works